# Oracle TOAD and Team Coding with TFS: Unable to get revisions from TFS

Tags: oracle, toad

My company is currently exploring the option of using TOAD as a means to seamlessly allow developers to check-in/check-out code in TFS. This would be seeded by our packages, stored procedures, etc. and put into an Oracle Database project in TFS. We are running a trial version of TOAD 11.6 on a virtual machine. When logging in, I had to create a new workspace and map it to a local folder on that machine. When I attempted to check-out a file, however, I was unable to as it stated it was 'unable to get revision from VCS repository'.

My question is... why is this happening? Is this because I haven't actually pulled down a copy of the project from TFS onto this file structure? Is there a way to do this through TOAD or is it assumed that I would map to a local folder on the machine and pull down a copy of the project beforehand? Does this have to do with me logging in through a VM and connecting? Any ideas?

Comment: I can connect to it and view it. If I check status, everything is checked and good to go.